# How to set Microsoft Exchange 2013 to mark off-domain Emails as spam

Tags: windows, email, exchange, spam-prevention, exchange-2013

We're getting emails with "no-reply@domain.com" or "scanner@domain.com", but do not have no-reply as a mailbox. Is there a way to say anyone without a mailbox with our domain reject as junk or spam? I am currently running Microsoft Exchange 2013 and have Symantec Mail security for exchange running, but it still seems like there's a lot of invalid emails getting through. I know in previous version I saw there seemed to be a more clear way of doing this.

Comment: Typical mailserver setup includes a default mailbox that accepts all mail for which there is not an actual address found. It escapes me what this is called in technical terms right now. But, you could set rules to run on this that any messages coming in get flagged as spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the following

```
Set-RecipientFilterConfig -Enabled $true
```

To enable filtering, then

```
Set-RecipientFilterConfig -RecipientValidationEnabled $true
```

To drop anything for an email address that doesn't exist.

*If this is on a server that doesn't include the edge server role you will need to install the agents with the following command

```
& $env:ExchangeInstallPath\Scripts\Install-AntiSpamAgents.ps1
```

Comment: This will reject it, not sure if you want to go that far or just drop it into spam

Comment: Rejecting the mail will work I just don't want the emails reaching the mailbox of the users